# Which color space should be used for a logo?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, cmyk, rgb, pantone

I'm currently designing a logo in CYMK (in Illustrator CS6). The logo will be used in digital printing, web and for business cards. Is it correct to use CYMK or would it better to use colors from Pantone/HKS?

If CMYK is the correct choice, is it good to export the logo from Illustrator for web publishing? Is there something that I need to ensure that the colors remain the same as in CYMK?

Comment: Hello julmot, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends, but often, for large branding projects, the logo may have a Pantone specification, a CMYK specification, and an RGB specification to handle all scenarios.

Comment: Ok and what is the best way to convert a logo that was creating in CYMK to all of this specifications?

Comment: Just change color space in illustrator from CMYK to RGB (sRGB, really) and check your resulting colors.

More [link](https://www.oss-usa.com/blog/color-distortions-web)

Comment: @julmot there's no 'one way' to convert between the color spaces. They are simply different color spaces and each software will have it's own way of converting between them. Your best bet is to convert and then tweak manually until you have it the way you want it visually. Trust your eyes.

Comment: For example (from past experience): 3M. When printing the red 3M logo, there's a Pantone Coated option, Pantone Uncoated option, CMYK option, Black/White option and an RGB/Hex option. They would have all been manually chosen to match (as best they can).

Comment: Ok I understand. But what is the advantage for a pantone/hks color? They are expensive and can not be used in digital printing. Why not just use the simple CMYK?

Comment: @julmot the advantage is that you can print more colors with pantone than CMYK and (often) you'll have a more consistent result across multiple printers. But in the end, if your client doesn't need Pantone, that's OK. CMYK is fine.

Comment: Thanks. At least one last question: If the logo is in CYMK and I want to provide the specifications for RGB, Pantone and HKS: What is the best way to provide the informations? I think most of us will see different things between two colors so if I would think that a color looks exactly like the one in CYMK, maybe a different person will not think so. Is there a common used way to determine the specifications?

Comment: They *will* be different colors. There's no way around that. But it's a judgement call by the designer, in the end.